# Is there an equivalent to "car" and "cdr" for "snoc"?

Tags: terminology, linked-lists

> Note: This question assumes familiarity with [cons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)-style linked lists (e.g., from Lisp or Scheme).
>
> It also assumes familiarity with snoc-style lists. Snoc is like cons, except it appends elements to the end of the list, instead of the beginning.

A cons is *car*/*cdr* pair.

> Alternatively, some people use the terms *head*/*tail*. For this question, let's treat these two conventions (i.e., car/cdr and head/tail) as interchangeable.

What about a snoc? **Is there a conventional name for the components of a snoc (e.g., *scdr*/*scar* or *body*/*foot*)?**

Comment: i suppose the first element (the rest of the list) would still be the car and the second element (the last item) would still be the cdr because the names car and cdr are just the names of two hardware registers from an obsolete computer system, not the names for the first item and remainder of a list.

Comment: The obvious names are *rac* and *rdc*. Some context would be nice.